# Spotty, glitchy, corrupted renderview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders, eevee-render-engine, error

I'm working on a large scene animation that has some issues. As you can see here, the viewport shading seems to be corrupted. This translates as well into the final render in cycles, although not as pronounced as seen here. It's not consistent and changes with every frame and camera movement, making animation impossible. The geometry is clean without any double faces or flipped normals etc.
Any idea what causes this? If I put in a new object like suzanne, the same thing happens to it. I also tried exporting the geometry into a fresh file, but get the same results there.
I'm using Optix with a 2080ti and 3900x in Blender 2.93 (also tried other Blender versions and CUDA with the same result).
Thanks for your help[image]

Comment: in Object data Properties did you try to go to Geometry Data and use Clear Custom split normals as well? (however it shouldn't affect that suzanne hmm , it will be something else. Are you using textures in  your materials? Are those islands of reflective surface your topology or is it random?)... Also you could add your file, If I open it and it will still have some problems, we at least know it is file issue

Comment: @mhess Upload .blender file ( or a piece that causes the problem)

Comment: Hi, yes, I cleared custom split normals with no effect. those reflective Islands on the left should not exist, it's supposed to be a pretty basic paint material, no textures. Same with the black spots on the darker parts, which is literally just a dark grey principled bsdf as seen here with medium roughness and no other inputs. Also the spots scale geometry subdivisions, the more divisions, the smaller the spots. Unfortunately I can't share the file because it is confidential, but I tried on another computer with the same results.